# how do i read video memory or Gpu

Tags: c#, python, image-processing, directx, gpu

i am creating a software to automate a game . my solution is take a screenshot and analysis it. but when the image is complex it is hard to analysis it.

for example if a minion come to screen (in 3d game) its hard to detect it etc.

i am looking for a way that i can read all resources on graphic card that being to render ...

i mean i want read graphic card ram or GPU then i can get an array of all object rendered on screen.

any solution for this ?

Comment: i don't think you want to read the GPU memory, for knowing all the "game-variables" you want to know you need to read them from the RAM. The GPU only does Transformation and drawing stuff. Calculation on the GPU is only for simulations (Physics in games or more complex stuff in science)

Comment: its true but as you know there are ways to automate a game one of those way is capture screen and image process (and safest way i think) i am doing this way . but hard work to process game image i am looking for an easy way for that.

Comment: it's simply not possible (without really complex analysis) for a complex 3d game, since you have to consider screensize, maybe colorblindmode, antialiasing, shader, and more stuff wich change the image before it's rendered.

Comment: is there any library or any code help to give me just object place (if with picture would better) on screen i think that is enough for me. no matter what programing language . i heared about CUDA can it does that.

Comment: since there is no *"standard"* object, that gets rendered there won't be any library for that, except for unity or UE4. Those two can be accessed somewhat generic. BUt anyway, you will have to write a lot of specific code for every single game you want to *"hack"*

Comment: that you even think that way shows me that you don't have the skills to solve this any time soon, even if it were possible that way. I don't want to discourage you but maybe you should start with something simpler?

Comment: ok thanks for answers and help ... seems there isnt easy way for that image process would be easier.

Comment: I guess there are better ways to waste your free time. there are already enough bots and cheats out there. try to make the world a better place instead.

Comment: @piglet i remember your advice